# Workspace struggles in R

Tags: r, workspace

I am unsure how workspaces work in R, but every time I load a previously saved workspace, all the objects from the current/default workspace remain there. I want to load a workspace with just objects from my previously saved work space - not extra objects added from my current workspace.

Comment: What code are you running to load workspaces? What are you actually doing that gives you the results you don't like?

Comment: I avoid loading and saving workspaces, and prefer regenerating the workspace based on the raw data and the R code. In this way you are certain that what is in the workspace matches with what is in the code. If some code takes a while, I sometimes save some objects using `save` and explicitely load them in the code using `load`.

Comment: I am using the default R drop down menus to load workspaces. And with datasets with millions of rows, regenerating a workspace is unfeasible.

Answer (score 2):

First, clear the current workspace using 'Session/Clear Workspace' and then 'Load (your) workspace)! That's what I regularly do working with large size workspaces.